# pktmon pcapng not working error unknown command

Tags: windows-server-2019

I am trying to convert a pktmon.etl logs to pcapng with below command:

`pktmon pcapng pktmon.etl capture.pcapng`

I am getting the below error:

> unknown command pcapng. see pktmon help

Any suggestions why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need the etl2pcapng.exe executable: https://github.com/microsoft/etl2pcapng